# 「ブロードキャスト」の意味について

Tags: android

androidアプリ開発でブロードキャストインテント、ブロードキャストレシーバといった用語が出てきます。
ブロードキャストとはこの場合どういった意味で使われているのでしょうか。教えてください。

Comment: FYI: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts

Answer (score 1):

[開発の基礎 | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals?hl=ja)

> ブロードキャスト レシーバ
>
> ブロードキャスト レシーバは、ブロードキャストの連絡を受信してそれに対処するだけのコンポーネントです。ブロードキャストの多くが元々はシステムコードで、たとえばタイムゾーンが変更されたこと、電池の残量が少なくなったこと、写真が撮影されたこと、ユーザーが言語設定を変更したことなどを連絡するために使用します。アプリケーションでも、たとえば何らかのデータがデバイスにダウンロードされて利用できるようになったことを、他のアプリケーションにブロードキャストで知らせることができます。
>
> アプリケーションでは、重要と思われるすべての連絡に応答できるよう、ブロードキャスト レシーバをいくつでも設定できます。すべてのレシーバは、BroadcastReceiver 基本クラスの拡張です。
>
> ブロードキャスト レシーバがユーザー インターフェースを表示することはありません。ただし、受信した情報への応答としてアクティビティを開始したり、NotificationManager を使用してユーザーにアラートを送信したりすることはあります。通知の際には、バックライトを点滅させる、バイブレーションを起動する、音を鳴らすなど、さまざまな方法でユーザーの注意を喚起できます。通常は、ステータス バーに永続アイコンを表示し、ユーザーがこれを開いてメッセージを取得できるようにします。

アプリケーション間メッセージングで 宛先がないのでブロードキャストなのではと思います。